# GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed Android App freezes and crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

My App freezes and crashes, I don't know why.

I have an MainActivity.java and its layout activity_main.xml in there I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemIconTint="#42858e"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in app_bar_main.xml I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.choix.myApp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:elevation="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGreen" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in the content_main.xml I'v got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="me.choix.myApp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use the @+id/content_frame as a container for my fragments, for example in mainActivity.java:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,new Test_Fragment(), "tag")
                        .addToBackStack("tag")
                        .commit();
```

The test_layout.xml has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#3d3d3d"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Hallo User!"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#3d3d3d" />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/flat_logo"
                    card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                    card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/startups"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#4dd0e1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:text="Latest Startups"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp" />
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/startup1"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/flat_logo"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup1"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup1"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup1"
                        android:src="@drawable/earth"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:src="@drawable/book"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:src="@drawable/flat_logo"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:src="@drawable/flat_logo"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup2"
                        android:src="@drawable/flat_logo"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startups"
            android:layout_below="@+id/startups"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#80deea"
            android:id="@+id/campaigns">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:text="Latest Campaigns"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp" />
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/startup11"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/startup22"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup1"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup1"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup1"
                        android:src="@drawable/startuplogo"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/startup3"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startup22"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startup22"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startup22"
                        android:src="@drawable/startuplogo2"
                        card_view:civ_border_color="@color/colorYellow"
                        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Test_Fragment.java:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Test_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    private SessionManager session;
    String ENDPOINT;
    String AMAZONS3;
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout,container,false);
        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(myView.getContext());

        //select the navigations drawer
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();

        if(session.isLoggedIn()) {
            //Toast.makeText(myView.getContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(myView.getContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.getUserDetails(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login).setVisible(false);
            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_register).setVisible(false);

            final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
            appBarLayout.setElevation(0f);
            appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorYellow));

            View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

            //select the circle image and set the avatar!
            TextView username_drawer = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
            TextView email_drawer = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.eamil);
            ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            ImageView profile_image = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            TextView welcome_tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.welcome_tv);


            ENDPOINT = getResources().getString(R.string.endpoint);
            AMAZONS3 = getResources().getString(R.string.amazonS3);

            HashMap<String, String> userDetails = session.getUserDetails();


            Log.d("UserDetails", userDetails.toString());

            //Test_Layout (Welcome Screen)
            Picasso.with(myView.getContext()).load(AMAZONS3 + userDetails.get("avatar")).into(profile_image);
            welcome_tv.setText("Welcome " + userDetails.get("first_name") + "!");

            //NavigationDrawer
            Picasso.with(myView.getContext()).load(AMAZONS3 + userDetails.get("avatar")).into(profileImage);
            email_drawer.setText(userDetails.get("email"));
            username_drawer.setText(userDetails.get("first_name"));

        }else{

            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login).setVisible(true);
            nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_register).setVisible(true);

        }

        return myView;
    }
}
```

Error:

> 02-19 18:54:45.643 23402-23507/me.choix.myApp E/Adreno-GSL:
>   : GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc
>   ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.663 23402-23507/me.choix.myApp
>   E/Adreno-GSL: : GSL MEM ERROR:
>   kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.693
>   23402-23507/me.choix.myAppE/Adreno-GSL:
>   : GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc
>   ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.714 23402-23507/me.choix.myApp
>   E/Adreno-GSL: : GSL MEM ERROR:
>   kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.735
>   23402-23507/me.choix.myAppE/Adreno-GSL:
>   : GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc
>   ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.754 23402-23507/me.choix.myApp
>   E/Adreno-GSL: : GSL MEM ERROR:
>   kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed. 02-19 18:54:45.821
>   23402-23507/me.choix.myAppE/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of
>   memory!

Comment: Facing same issue on Samsung J4 and Samsung J4 Plus only while application works on all other devices including Samsung phones.

Comment: I solved it, but I really don't know how :(

Comment: One of the case, I found while researching it is that if we are using Volley then we need to remember to create a single instance object of RequestQueue and reuse it for all calls. I applied that and seems app working fine for now. But still looking for more cases for same issue.